# Create a micro-frontend architecture using Webpack 5 Module Federation plugin and Google Cloud Platform

Tags: webpack, google-cloud-platform, micro-frontend

Can anybody give a hint on how to create a micro-frontend architecture using Webpack 5 Module Federation plugin and Google Cloud Platform?
**I'm mostly interested in GCP setup.**
Everything works as expected on my local env. I would like to know how to set up something similar to AWS web distribution on GCP.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in GCP’s App Engine Flexible Environment. In the following tutorial, you are going to see an example with a Node.js app built with Express.js that uses Webpack to bundle frontend assets on deployment to the App Engine Flexible environment [Webpack on App Engine flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/appengine-nodejs-webpack). As I mentioned, that first one is for App Engine Flexible Environment, but the following URL has official Google Firebase’s documentation, this time focused on Firebase, in case that you could need it in the future [Using module bundlers with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/module-bundling) . Finally, regarding the Web Distribution part on GCP, it has an option called Cloud CDN (Content Delivery Network), which works with external HTTP(S) Load Balancing to deliver content to your users. The external HTTP(S) load balancer provides the frontend IP addresses and ports that receive requests and the backends that respond to the requests. In the following URL, you will find the official GCP’s documentation for that [Cloud CDN overview](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/overview).